# In perl the exec command does not work under windows 10

Tags: windows, perl

Here is a very simple script that works under Windows 7 fine, but with Windows 10 it does not work. The exec command is waiting on the console of an input. I don´t know where the problem is.

```
#bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our $EXTERN=$ARGV[0];

$EXTERN +=1;

print __LINE__. ">>> Extern $EXTERN  $$\n\n";

if ($EXTERN <=10){
    exec ("perl exec_test.pl $EXTERN");
}   
exit();
```

Comment: Does it print ok for this code: `if ($EXTERN <=10){ print "OK" }`?

Comment: What is printed for this code: 1. `print exec ''` 2. `print exec 'echo'` 3. `print exec 'perl -c exit'`?

Comment: Check the environment variable PATH. Is it avalable to run perl from any folder?